# Airflow is having deadlock in backend database with MSSQL , Same Dag is working fine in postgresql backed

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

`I am trying to run a Dag with MSSQL version 19, backend and airflow version as 2.5.0

below is the DAG:

```
``*import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta

# Define the DAG with timezone 
dag = DAG("my_tz_dag", start_date=pendulum.datetime(2016, 1, 1, tz="Europe/Amsterdam"), schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=15))

# Define the task function
def print_hello():
    print("Hello, world!")

# Define the task using the PythonOperator
task = PythonOperator(task_id="print_hello", python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)`

`
```

- 

I am getting this in logs and scheduler goes down

Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 194) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: UPDATE dag_run SET last_scheduling_decision=?, updated_at=? WHERE dag_run.id = ?]
[parameters: ((datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 18, 43, 12, 737104, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')),

[Scheduler goes down with this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VbHX.png)

I tried without giving timezone as well ,as below but this one does not start it self .Manual Trigger works fine , But scheduling does not work,

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 1),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'log_cleaning',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
    catchup=False
)
log_cleaning = BashOperator(
    task_id='log_cleaning',
    bash_command='find /usr/local/airflow/logs/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;',
    dag=dag
)
```

``

Comment: Mssql as backend is experimintal. If there is reproduce example please open Github issue to Airflow.

Comment: Thank for reply . Is it experimental for all the airflow version , As the official documentation it is experimental with few version only ?

Comment: See: https://github.com/apache/airflow#requirements

Comment: Its experimintal because we wait for users feedback this is why its important to report issues